# Vertical images change to horizontal when converted to PDF Python Pillow

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, pdf-generation, converters

i want to print all picures in a folder into a PDF.
I take pictures with my phone and need to convert them into a PDF that i can send to other people.
Because the both Windows and Adobe Print to PDF mess up the cronological oder of the pictures
i wanted to create it on my own.

My problem is every time i try to convert a vertical image it get rotated to horizontal.

My first attempt was this.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

current_dir = os.getcwd()

pdf_filename = 'Auskundung.pdf'

pdf_path = os.path.join(current_dir, pdf_filename)

image_filenames = os.listdir(current_dir)

images = []

for filename in image_filenames:
    if filename.endswith('.jpg') or filename.endswith('.png'):
        image = Image.open(os.path.join(current_dir, filename))   
        images.append(image)

images[0].save(pdf_path, "PDF" ,resolution=100.0, save_all=True, append_images=images[1:])

print("PDF erstellt!")
```

Horizontal pictures convert as they should but vertical pictures get turned 90° to be horizonal.
I tried to get around this by turing the pictures before saving them.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

folder_path = os.getcwd()

for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if file.endswith(".png") or file.endswith(".jpg"):
        image = Image.open(os.path.join(folder_path, file))


        if image.width < image.height:
            image = image.rotate(270, expand=True)

        pdf_file = file.split('.')[0] + '.pdf'
        image.save(os.path.join(folder_path, pdf_file))
```

This however did nothing.
As soon as i swap the < for a > thogh, it rotates all pictures horizontal and vertical ones leading me to belive the vertical pictures get autorotated to horizontal right after opening.

But i dont know how to combat this.

I just want all picutes in that Folder to get converted to a single PDF.
Pictues should be in chronological order, oldest first. (That already works becasue of the picutes being named by date i suppose)
Pictures need to keep their original orientation.

Comment: This [github issue](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4703#issuecomment-645219973) could help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. This could solve my problem.